# Shiny dropdown menu selection to filter a dataframe

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I've got a question about Shiny, dropdown selections and filtering on that selection.

I have the dropdown list; easy enough but I'm having a difficult time taking that input and then filtering a dataframe based on that value. I keep getting "can only be done inside a reactive expression" errors.

For the Shiny App

```
library(dtplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

citylist <- data.frame("City" = c("Abilene", "Amarillo", "Omaha"))
wxdata <- data.frame("City" = c("Abilene", "Abilene", "Abilene", "Abilene", "Amarillo", "Amarillo", "Amarillo", "Amarillo", "Omaha", "Omaha", "Omaha", "Omaha"), "Temp" = c(12,15, 16,17,32,34,36,37,8,6,3,4))

ui <- fluidPage(
  inputPanel(selectInput("PlotCity",
                         label = "Select City",
                         choices = citylist)),
  
  plotOutput(outputId = 'minplot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 
  plotmin <- as.data.frame(subset(wxdata, City == input$PlotCity))

  minplot <- ggplot(data from plotmin DF)

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'm stuck on this and I'm willing to bet its a simple solution but I can't figure out the "reactive" thing.

Anyway thanks for any help

Rob

Answer (score 3):

`citylist` ought to be a vector, not a data frame. Try defining `citylist <- unique(wxdata$City)` after you define `wxdata`.

I think the reactive error is because you haven't called `renderPlot()`.

I find Shiny apps easiest to reason about if you separate the logic for drawing plots (or other calculations) into their own functions, so that the server code is only about rendering.

Here's my version of your dashboard.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

wxdata <- data.frame(
  City = rep(c("Abilene", "Amarillo", "Omaha"), each = 4), 
  Temp = c(12, 15, 16, 17, 32, 34, 36, 37, 8, 6, 3, 4)
)
citylist <- unique(wxdata$City)

draw_plot <- function(city_to_filter_by) {
  filtered_wx <- wxdata %>%
    filter(City == !!city_to_filter_by)
  ggplot(filtered_wx, aes(Temp)) +
    geom_histogram()
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  inputPanel(
    selectInput(
      "PlotCity",
      label = "Select City",
      choices = citylist
    )
  ),
  plotOutput('minplot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$minplot <- renderPlot(draw_plot(input$PlotCity))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```